# Split one large file into multiple InputStream(s) to be processed in multithreading in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, file, inputstream

My codes:

```
public ArrayList<InputStream> getAllInputStreams() {
    ArrayList<InputStream> allStreams = new ArrayList<InputStream>();
    InputStream stream = this.getNext();
    while (stream != null) {
        allStreams.add(stream);
        stream = this.getNext();
    }
    return allStreams;
}

public InputStream getNext() {
    if (done()) {
        return null;
    }
    InputStream segment = createInputStream();
    this.countStream++;
    return segment;
}

protected InputStream createInputStream() {
    BoundedInputStream res = new BoundedInputStream(
            Channels.newInputStream(this.randomAccessFile.getChannel().position(this.countStream * chunkSize)), chunkSize);
    res.setPropagateClose(false) ;
    return res ;
}
```

I am trying to split `file` into several InputStream(s) (`private RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");`. All InputStream(s) (got from `getAllInputStreams()`) to be processed by multiple threads, it seems that most of them are empty. Why?

Any hints welcomed. Thanks

**UPDATE**

It seems that the following piece of codes working fine. Is the following piece of codes a good way to split the file into several chucks? Should the size of each chuck smaller than memory size?

```
protected InputStream createInputStream() {
    RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
    BoundedInputStream res = new BoundedInputStream(
            Channels.newInputStream(randomAccessFile.getChannel().position(this.countStream * chunkSize)), chunkSize);
    res.setPropagateClose(false) ;
    return res ;
}
```

Comment: `if (done()) { return null;`  Because most of them are "done"?  Really I don't see how we could tell from the code you have shown.

Comment: What makes you think that using multiple streams that read from the same IO device, just in different locations will **speed up** things? Depending on the underlying hardware and software stack, you might actually see a slow down. Because your truly random read accesses to the **same** IO device will generate a lot of overhead.

Comment: @GhostCat, so, any way to speed up things? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that this statement:

```
      res.setPropagateClose(false);
```

in your "UPDATE" solution will result in a resource leak.  The RAF that you have opened is not shared with anything else.  When the `BoundedInputStream` is closed, you *need* the close to propagate to the RAF.

Answer (score 0):

can try this:

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
inputStream.skip(startPos);
BoundedInputStream partInputStream = new BoundedInputStream(inputStream, curPartSize);
```

---

this also need new FileInputStream every time, so it's useless.