# Java: multiple threads read the same InputStream at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading, inputstream, fileinputstream

There is `private InputStream inputStream;`. Now, I would like to split the inputStream into 10 chunks, which return another 10 InputStream. 10  threads will read the 10 InputStream at the same time. How to do this?

Does the following piece of codes work?

```
BoundedInputStream stream = new BoundedInputStream(inputStream, chunkSize);
```

Comment: This one? ["(BoundedInputStream) will only supply bytes up to a certain length - if its position goes above that, it will stop."](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/input/BoundedInputStream.html)

Comment: In general, each thread must have it's *own* InputStream (or provide the necessary synchronization over a shared object), to prevent race-conditions. If a specific InputStream implementation *is* thread-safe, it will *explicitly claim so* in the documentation (and under which conditions / expected state).

Comment: You can clone the original inputstream to 10 inputsteams (There should be methed to clone a inputstream) and use ```skip``` to set position for each thread.

Comment: An `InputStream` is for reading bytes *sequentially*, so how did you envision reading from multiple places at the same time? You can't split an `InputStream` like that.

Comment: @zhh - The `clone()` method will not work on an `InputStream`.  And there is no other method to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code does not do what you think.  A [`BoundedInputStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/input/BoundedInputStream.html) is a stream that limits the number of bytes that can be read from the underlying stream.  But it doesn't say *which* bytes will be returned ... if other threads are also reading from the underlying stream.

For an input stream that is reading from a non-file source, the only way to divide the stream into chunks is to read the whole stream, write it to something that can be chunked, then open separate input streams on the chunks.

If the source is a file, you could open multiple independent input streams, use `seek` or equivalent to skip to the required position and read.  For example (based on [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51566645)):

```
public InputStream chunkInputStream(File file, int pos, int count) {
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
    BoundedInputStream res = new BoundedInputStream(
         Channels.newInputStream(raf.getChannel().position(pos)), 
         count);
    //  res.setPropagateClose(false) ;  // INCORRECT!
    return res ;
}
```

In fact, you can avoid the `RandomAccessFile` and do this:

```
public InputStream chunkInputStream(File file, int pos, int count) {
    FileChannel channel = FileChannel.open(file, READ);
    return new BoundedInputStream(
         Channels.newInputStream(channel.position(pos)), 
         count);
}
```

... but the differences are purely cosmetic.

Comment: Is the piece of codes in the UPDATE of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51566645/how-to-split-one-file-into-multiple-inputstream-as-chunk-in-java a good way to open multiple independent input streams?

Comment: It looks OK.  Have you **tried** it?  (Note that it won't work for all input stream types ...)

Comment: I tired. it works fine. But I am trying to find some better solutions.

Comment: What is wrong with it?  Why do you need to find a better solution?

Comment: There is a bug in that solution, I think.  It shouldn't `setPropagateClose(false)` ... since it "owns" the RAF.   Setting that will (I think) lead to a resource leak.

Comment: Thanks. btw, do I have to create multiple RAF(s)? Can I use a RAF, but have multiple Channels. each Channel maintains an independent `position`?

Comment: Yes, you do need multiple RAFs.  The `getChannel()` method returns a RAF's one and only `Channel`.  (**Read the javadoc!!**) If you try to use one RAF, all of your streams will share one channel, and you are back to square one.